# Use Dynamic key for hashMap in Thymeleaf, along with attribute

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am doing my first project with Thymeleaf. And most of my work is done... except for this below part.

```
<img th:attrappend="src='file:///' + ${entryImageMap['__${entry.id}__']}"></img>
```

This is the error I get from Thymeleaf

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "entryImageMap['83383894']" (template: "Report.html" - line 89, col 6)
```

I have tried minor variations. This is how I progressed through various wrong ones, and still its not clear.

```
<img th:attrappend="src=file:///${entryImageMap.(entry.id)}"></img>
<img th:attrappend="src=file:///${entryImageMap[__${entry.id}__]}"></img>
<img th:attrappend="src='file:///' + ${entryImageMap[__${entry.id}__]}"></img>
<img th:attrappend="src='file:///' + ${entryImageMap['__${entry.id}__']}"></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
<img th:attrappend="src='file:///' + ${data.entryImageMap.get('__${entry.id}__')}"></img>
```

I had done a mistake of assuming `entryImageMap` was in the root. Whereas, it was inside `data` object.

Few of the above cases would have worked, if I had used `data.entryImageMap` properly.